# Merging jQuery Mobile CSS into JavaScript output elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a little form with 3 input type text/number elements and a button.

The script gets the values entered when the user clicks on the button and these values are then appended on a `<ul /> <li />` List.

However, the elements appended don't have the jQuery Mobile CSS style.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5nCS/51/) where you can see the code I have been working on and how it behaves.

I tried using some ideas from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478759/jquery-mobile-elements-not-displaying-properly) post but no matter how I change it around and adding the `$(".config").trigger("create");` (I changed the names to fit my code when testing) it only makes the `button` look jQueryMobile style but the remove function doesn't work anymore.

Here's the code (incase you know the solution without looking at the demo):

```
<input type="text" id="MedNameStren" name="MedNameStren" placeholder="MedName & Strength" />
<input type="number" data-clear-btn="false" id="MedQuantity" name="MedQuantity" min="1" max="50" value ="1" />
<textarea cols="40" rows="4" name="MedDirections" id="MedDiresctions" placeholder="Type any directions written on your prescription for the above medicine." ></textarea>
<input type="button" id="AddScript" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right" value="Add New Prescription" />

<ul class="justList"></ul> 

$('#AddScript').click(function(){
var text = '<h2>' + $('#MedNameStren').val() + '</h2>' + 
           '<p><strong>Quantity: </strong>' + $('#MedQuantity').val() + '</p>' +
           '<p><strong>Directions: </strong>' + $('#MedDiresctions').val() + '</p>' +
           '<button>Delete</button>';

    if(text.length){
      $('<li />', {html:text}).appendTo('ul.justList')
    }
});

$('ul').on('click','button' , function(el){
    $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

Also, it would be nice if you could give me an idea of how to prevent the button from appending a new `<li>` if the `MedNameStren` and `MedDirections` are empty (The spinner will always display a number 1).
Any suggestions or guide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this answers all your questions http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LQtYC/

Comment: Oh, when adding it to my project I noticed it only changes the `<button>` to jQueryMobile but it doesnt change the `<li>`, this still remains standard CSS. Anyway I could tell the JS to take jQueryMobile structure CSS?

Comment: Give `ul` an attribute `data-role="listview"`. And after you append a new item, call `$('ul').listview('refresh');`

Comment: You rock! Thanks a lot! All works perfectly now :) - You can place your comments in a proper answer so I can tick/accept it, if you wish. That way this question could be set as answered! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark this question as answered, I would like to place here the solution @Omar has posted in the comments above.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LQtYC/) was written and provided by @Omar and it truly solved my issue, by adding the following to the JS:

```
$('button').button();
```

The differences can be seen by comparing both my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5nCS/51/) and [Omar's](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LQtYC/). Hope this helps anyone.